# Chatbot with specific purpose which can also handle all the basic things like joke and search queries

Tags: nlp, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, google-assistant-sdk

I am developing a chatbot which has certain functionalities. But during interaction with the chatbot, the user can ask anything from jokes to 'Who is the prime minister of Australia'. Possibilities of what user can ask are endless. I can't handle all these basic possibilities in my chatbot. But at the same time, I want to keep it smart to handle everything.

I was exploring some possibilities to invoke Alexa and Google Assistant programmatically and get the response. But it seems it is not possible.

Is there any bot framework or service which can handle all these generic and basic queries by itself?

Comment: I don't think I violated anything to get a down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) is designed to let a user programmatically send queries to the Assistant. By registering [custom device actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview) you can add your own functionality to respond to things like "tell a joke".